# How to get double value with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, ssms, sqldatareader

I'm trying read data from sql database. When I run the code, it gives an error when it comes to where it should read data.

> "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."

I get an error. I researched my mistake but couldn't find the solution that works for me. While the query text I wrote works in ssms, it does not work in code.

```
 private void pbx_frame_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) //
    {
        //take cropped image to picture box of crooped images
        try
        {
            string[] resim = lbx_raw_image.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace(':','.').Split('.'); 
            string sorgu_sql = "Data Source=DESKTOP-OON7EET\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Target;Integrated Security=True;"; //sql bağlantısı kuruldu
            //string query = "SELECT * FROM MP_Data$ WHERE time= '19.53.06'"; //'" + lbx_raw_image.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'"; //time=19.53.06 tek bir veriyi çağrır. muhtemelen yorum haline getirilen kısım olacaktı.
            string query = "SELECT * FROM MP_DATA_15_mayıs_2019$ WHERE time='" + lbx_raw_image.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'"; //12.50.23
            DB_islem db = new DB_islem(sorgu_sql, query); // 
            
            pic_info_from_MP = db.Raw_Image(pic_info_from_MP);      



    public Target Raw_Image(Target pic_info) 
    {
        sql.Open();
       
        sql_read = sql_command.ExecuteReader();

        //while (sql_read.Read())
        if (sql_read.Read())
        {
            pic_info.lat = sql_read.GetDouble(0);
            pic_info.lon = sql_read.GetDouble(1);
            pic_info.alt = sql_read.GetDouble(2);
            pic_info.yaw = sql_read.GetDouble(3);
        }

        sql.Close();

        return pic_info;
    }
```

[image: the query wokrs in ssms]

[image: edited after warnings]

SOLUTİON:

```
ALTER TABLE table1(name of table) ALTER COLUMN clmn1(name of column) float(datatype);
```

I determined datatype for each column using the above query. helped me to call the required data.

Comment: If time = '12.50.23', why do you replace colons earlier in the code, but not in the query? And parameterize your query for security, performance and accuracy

Comment: https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I guess it is your alt value. SSMS might handle this but in c#, double is limited to 16 digits, hence this value has too many decimals. Try with type decimal instead.

Comment: Show the table definition please

Comment: As @LocEngineer says, value in alt column can be too long. Also you can have more values that are problematic on other columns, as you used where clause and we do not see everything.

Comment: '12.50.23' is my test file name. I choose 12.50.23 file on the list and try

Comment: Also i tried GetFloat and i reached the same error. When i tried GetDecimal and i get error that convert type 'decimal' to 'double'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason I asked for the table definition is because there are particular column types on the DB side that map to particular data types on the C# side. The screenshot posted is not enough to realistically determine the column types. The lat and long aren't `real`, otherwise they'd be truncated but other than that we can't really say

Broadly speaking:

- If you've used `real` column type, call `GetFloat(..)`
- If you've used `float` column type, call `GetDouble(..)`
- If you've used `decimal`(or `numeric`) column type, call `GetDecimal(..)`

GetXxx will not convert for you because it does an unboxing cast. If your reader has a `decimal` in column 0 you can only call `GetDecimal` on it. You cannot call `GetDouble` and expect you really-a-decimal to be converted to a double, for the same reason as this doesn't work:

```
object o = 0.1m; //decimal boxed inside object
double d = (double)o;
```

Unboxing casts and converting casts are different things. If you want your decimal-in-an-object as a double you have to cast twice, once to unbox and once to convert:

```
object o = 0.1m; //decimalboxed inside object
double d = (double)(decimal)o;
```

Similarly if your thing inside reader column 0 is a `decimal` and you want a `double` you must get it as a decimal, because that's what it really is, and then convert it:

```
var dbl = (double)reader.GetDecimal(0);
```

Simple rule:

- Pull it out according to what it really is, then convert it

As to what you have, we don't know; your `yaw` could be a `real` and cannot be `GetDouble`'d (has to be `GetFloat`'d). Your `alt` is probably a decimal (do you really need altitude to the tenth of a picometer/pico-ft?) and cannot be `GetDouble`'d (has to be `GetDecimal`'d) .. but you have all the necessary info to solve this one yourself.

If all else fails and the above just went completely over your head "try changing GetDouble to GetDecimal for the line that doesn't work. And if that doesn't work, try changing it to GetFloat. And if that doesn't work, supply the table definition and we'll tell you what it should be"

Update: youve indicated they're all varchar. Personally I would convert them to float or real - open SSMS, Design the table, change the column type to eg float and save the table. Then they can be GetDouble'd

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As you said, I looked at the table definition and it says nvarchar for all columns. I imported the excel tables to database. probably this data type is default type cause i didn't choose any data type. Now, It's time the real question. how to call varchar data from database or how to change datatype of the columns?

Comment: Personally I think I would alter the table so the columns were all FLOAT, which would convert the data too. If about 7 decimal places would do you could use REAL for all columns and halve the bytes needed to store the data

Answer (score -3):

First of all you should execute your queries ONLY with parameters.
Secondly, we don't know your table schema - please show it.

But most probably there is problem in how you store this value. GetDouble doesn't do any conversions, so your data should already be saved as double.

What's more, there can be problem with globalization. What you should do is:

```
using System.Globalization;
//...

double result = double.NaN;

if(!sql_read.IsDbNull(0))
{
    string s = sql_read.GetString(0);
    result = Convert.ToDouble(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: I massively disagree that tripping everything through a string is what someone "should do"

Comment: Especially since you can pass Object to Convert.ToDouble, so `Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetValue(i))`

Comment: I disagree - there may be problems with decimal separator. When playing with different cultures.